# check for multiple substring match in a list while iterating list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get the elements in a list that match by substring while iterating over it.
For instance, in following example list, i want to get `"pass1"`, `"pass2"` matching elements and `"pass3"` as element that doesn't match. This is a simplified version of the list, as I need to iterate over the long list.

Please, let me know, what am I doing wrong in the following example.

```
keyList=["pass1_v1","pass1_v3","pass1_v5","pass2_v1","pass2_v3","pass3_v4"]
for x in keyList:
    match=x.rsplit("_",1)[0] ## splitting the list elements seperated by "_"..eg:- pass1 to check how many elements match
    if  match in keyList:
        print("matching are %s" %x) ## expecting to print eg:-pass1_v1 and pass1_v3
    else :
        print ("non matching are %s"%x)     # expecting to print pass3_v4
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `pass3` is also a substring in the list (the last element). Do you mean that it has to match _other_ elements in the list?

Comment: Your code splits off `pass1` in the first loop, in which case all the `pass2` and `pass3` elements would *not* match that prefix. Next two iterations the same would happen. Then a `pass2` prefix is found, and it appears you want all `pass1` and `pass3` elements to be printed as 'not matching'; twice as there are two `pass2` elements in the list. That's a lot of extra `non matching` prints..

Comment: Hi ..Thanks for the quick reply...yup, it is the substring in the list and should also be checked as others...and the result should show "pass3_v4" as non matched, as pass3 isn't contained by other elements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `in` membership testing with a substring; you'd have to loop over `keyList` *again* to test each substring.

It'd be far more efficient to grou all strings by prefix:

```
by_prefix = {}
for x in keyList:
    by_prefix.setdefault(x.rsplit('_', 1)[0], []).append(x)

for prefix, matches in by_prefix.iteritems():
    print 'Matches for {} are {}'.format(prefix, by_prefix[prefix])
```

This only prints the matching elements; all *other* keys are those that didn't match, but they'll be printed on their own:

```
>>> keyList = ["pass1_v1", "pass1_v3", "pass1_v5", "pass2_v1", "pass2_v3", "pass3_v4"]
>>> by_prefix = {}
>>> for x in keyList:
...     by_prefix.setdefault(x.rsplit('_', 1)[0], []).append(x)
... 
>>> for prefix, matches in by_prefix.iteritems():
...     print 'Matches for {} are {}'.format(prefix, by_prefix[prefix])
... 
Matches for pass2 are ['pass2_v1', 'pass2_v3']
Matches for pass1 are ['pass1_v1', 'pass1_v3', 'pass1_v5']
Matches for pass3 are ['pass3_v4']
```